# iOS versions supported by entgraiot server

Tags: wso2, entgraiot

What are the exact iOS versions supported by Entgra IoT server for iOS MDM. WSO2 based versions supported upto iOS 11 and does Entgra server support more?

Answer (score 2):

Entgra IoT server which is the latest version of WSO2 IoT server supports upto the latest version of iOS at any given time. Lowest version is iOS 8

Comment: This is a superficial answer. How did you determine that information? Your statement won't necessarily always be true, so a link to the relevant documentation would be helpful.

Comment: Apologies on not attaching my reference -https://entgra.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IoTS350/pages/336562317/iOS+Device